# How do I 302 redirect all traffic to the homepage using .htaccess? Avoid infinite redirect loop?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, infinite-loop

How can I redirect all traffic on my site to the homepage?

We are redesigning a site for a client. On their current hosting we removed their old site, and put up a landing page (http://norbutconstruction.com/) as their main index.

This is the code I have in a .htaccess file doing the redirect:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   #Redirect all of the traffic to the temporary landing page
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

When I try to visit a page Google has indexed (http://www.norbutconstruction.com/contact-us) this results in an infinite loop. As long as I've been working with .htaccess files I seem to remember writing rules that result in infinite loops. I know this should be something very simple, but I can't even find an example of how to do this.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to get this code to work, or any general suggestions on how to avoid infinite loops in the .htaccess redirects? I always seem to have trouble with these.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   #Redirect all of the traffic to the temporary landing page
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*index\.php
   RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I just had to add these lines:
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
because I had a reference to an image in that file which was being redirected as well.